# What do you call an episode that is not closely related to the main plot?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In some TV shows, in order to develop a character, there may be some episodes that are not closely related to the main story, e.g., an episode of the background story of a supporting character explaining his motivation or why he becomes the very person he is.

What do you call an episode of this type?

Comment: There might be industry jargon for this, along the lines of "ship in a bottle". I'd ask this question at [Movies and TV.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @gotube: A [bottle episode](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BottleEpisode) is an episode designed to be *cheap*, regardless of how it relates to the main plot. However, bottle episodes in practice do tend to focus more on characterization and/or worldbuilding, so it is still relevant to some extent.

Comment: The answer to this question might have been different before, say the 1990s, when it was the norm for a TV series to have no series-wide plot at all - in which case _all_ episodes were standalone; the notion of "filler" or "non-arc" don't apply if there's no arc and hence nothing to fill.

Comment: @gotube Bottle episodes usually have few or no guest stars, no special sets or location shots, etc. to be inexpensive. But there's no reason they still couldn't fit into the overall arc.

Comment: Great question and piles of great answers!

Comment: @Kevin while "bottle" ep. is a good term to know, it is not what is being asked here.

Comment: @Fattie: Hence why my comment was not an answer.

Comment: I thought the key defining point of a bottle episode is that the characters are in some way trapped for most of the story.  E.g. stuck in a broken elevator, jailcell, in traffic, etc.  The whole story takes place in one location, not because it's cheap (even if it is), but as a plot device to prevent the characters from escaping, thus adding tension.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another term that is commonly used for this situation would be a "filler episode." However, in this case, the term means that the episode is not considered important viewing for the overall plot. It's possible that a side character's motivation may not be considered filler if the viewer considers it to be important.

"Filler episode" also has a more negative connotation than "standalone episode." The former implies that the viewer could skip the episode if they choose, while the latter does not.

Comment: Sorry, yes: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Episodes#:~:text=Recap%20Episode%3A%20Episode%20that%20sums,didn't%20end%20after%20it

Comment: "Filler" has the connotation that they threw it together because it was too much effort to get one that advanced the story.

Comment: @Mary: I'd say that depends heavily on the type of show. In the anime world, for example, filler means it's something not in the manga it's based on. There are also somewhat older US TV shows where, due to the number of episodes per season, it was always expected there would be filler episodes.

Answer (score 18):

If it doesn't fit neatly into an overall story arc, then it is often called a "[standalone episode](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StandAloneEpisode)" (or a "self-contained episode"). It may also be described as "[episodic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/episodic)".

Comment: Perhaps also "one-off-", an example here: [The Best One-Off Episodes...](https://www.comingsoon.net/tv/pb_article_type/1013404-the-best-one-off-episodes-in-tv-history)

Comment: I think episodic means the TV is made up of episodes that are not closely related. Say, the Family Guy is one example, each episode is an independent story.

Answer (score 6):

Another term for this is **non-arc** episode, one that is not part of the story arc.

Answer (score 6):

These can be [flashback](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flashback) or [backstory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backstory) episodes.

Answer (score 3):

You could call them [monster of the week](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MonsterOfTheWeek) episode.

Comment: This is only used for sci-fi/fantasy shows, like X-Files. And it normally describes the general approach, not occasionally outlier episodes.

Comment: @Barmar I'd call it MooW no matter the genre.

Comment: Monster-of-the-week could still be important for plot, though. E.g. the Buffy musical episode is definitely monster-of-the-week (the actual monster is completely wrapped up at the end and never seen again) but also crucial for plot. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_More,_with_Feeling_(Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer)

Answer (score 1):

An episode that develops the overall setting of the story, but not the story itself, may be called "worldbuilding". An episode that doesn't have any usefulness at all, other than taking up time, is referred to as "filler". Opinions may vary as to which category particular episodes fall in.

Answer (score 1):

Offshoot

> "a side shoot or branch on a plant" or "a thing that originated or
> developed from something else"

Answer (score 1):

Informally I've heard this called a "character arc", though everything I can find online says that formally, that term should refer to a character's development rather than specific episodes or a specific section of the book.

Comment: Yeah, I think this phrase is about the story centred around a certain character. Nevertheless, it's a useful piece of info.